# Implementing dynamic menu with spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am making own website using Spring MVC (Version 3.1)

I would like to load dynamic menu with each role, but I have no idea for this job. Could you give me any suggestion.

I am newbie in Spring MVC and hope you can help me.

Thank you.

Example:

In each controller, I define a method for view

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UsrMgmt.do")
@Override
public String view(Model model) {
    MenuVO menu = smt.getMenu();
    model.setAttribute("menu", model);
    return "UsrMgmtView";
}
```

and if I use menu, I have to get menu, but I don't want to do like this.
I have no idea for implementing this function.

Comment: if you use spring security you can use http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html `<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">`

Comment: Could you explain more about this? I updated my question.

Comment: what exactly is the question? :) and do you use spring security or how do you know which user has which role? and do I get you right: you don't have problem with menu rendering but with preparation of MenuVO?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create dynamic menu based on role using `<c:test>`.
First you have to include `core` library using `<%@taglib>` and set role after logging user then you can check condition for role like
`<c:test admin!=null>
     menu for admin
 </c:test>
 <c:test user!=null>
     menu for user
 </c:test>`